# I can't install pg in Slackware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, slackware

I need to run a ruby project with gems and specs. When I type bundle install I received:

```
bash-5.1# bundle install
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 2.3.9
Using diff-lcs 1.5.0
Using rspec-support 3.1.2
Fetching pg 1.3.4
Using rspec-core 3.1.7
Using rspec-expectations 3.1.2
Using rspec-mocks 3.1.3
Using rspec 3.1.0
Installing pg 1.3.4 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.3.4/ext
/usr/bin/ruby -I /usr/lib64/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20220320-7556-sm89ck.rb
extconf.rb
Calling libpq with GVL unlocked
checking for pg_config... no
checking for libpq per pkg-config... no
Using libpq from 
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*****************************************************************************

Unable to find PostgreSQL client library.

Please install libpq or postgresql client package like so:
  sudo apt install libpq-dev
  sudo yum install postgresql-devel
  sudo zypper in postgresql-devel
  sudo pacman -S postgresql-libs

or try again with:
  gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config

or set library paths manually with:
gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/path/to/libpq-fe.h/
--with-pg-lib=/path/to/libpq.so/

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-gvl-unlock
    --disable-gvl-unlock
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-libpq-config
    --without-libpq-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib64

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/pg-1.3.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.3.4 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/pg-1.3.4/gem_make.out

  /usr/lib64/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:93:in `run'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:47:in `block in build'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tempfile-0.1.2/lib/tempfile.rb:317:in `open'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in `build'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
/usr/lib64/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:193:in `block in
build_extensions'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:190:in `each'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:190:in `build_extensions'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:845:in `build_extensions'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:71:in
`build_extensions'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
`install'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:204:in
`install'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in
`do_install'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in
`block in worker_pool'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in
`apply_func'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in
`block in process_queue'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`loop'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`process_queue'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/worker.rb:91:in
`block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing pg (1.3.4), and Bundler cannot
continue.

In Gemfile:
  pg
```

I am trying to convince them to switch to Slackware as the main OS but I am having trouble installing and running the skeleton program that uses psql, ruby and soon enough ruby on rails.

I installed libpqxx slackbuild, sqlite3 gem,  postgresql (14.2)  slackbuild and when I run rnu ./import_db.sh it says: bash-5.1# ./import_db.sh
dropdb: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
createdb: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
bash-5.1#

Comment: Have you tried what the error says to do so? `Unable to find PostgreSQL client library. Please install libpq or postgresql client package like so:...`

Comment: bash-5.1$ su
Password: 
bash-5.1# gem install libpq
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'libpq' (>= 0) in any repository
bash-5.1# gem install postgressql
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'postgressql' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: postgresql, postgressor, em_postgresql, mv-postgresql, postgres, postgres-pr, postgres_ext, postgresable, postgression, postgrest
bash-5.1#

Comment: `libpq` isn't a gem. I meant to check the lines after `Please install libpq or postgresql client package like so`, where it says about **installing** the dev libraries. I've never used it Slackware before, but I can see 4 commands starting with `sudo` there and hopefully one of them will work with your distro. Worst case, look what's the Slackware package manager and see how to install the PostgreSQL dev libraries with it.

Comment: @Masterofpuppets try checking error log in `/var/log/postgresql` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just realised that Slackware uses `slackpkg` as package manager.
Not quite sure if [this](https://slackbuilds.org/repository/15.0/libraries/libpqxx/) is the library you need, but try installing with:

```
slackpkg install libpqxx
```

Comment: OKay I got the bundler to work but how do I start psql locally so I can run a script to start up the db?

Comment: I Installed it with a slackbuild. Thank you. Gems also work in slackware.